Wordpress redirects when apply a rewrite rule
I created the page /directors and added this rewrite rule to get /directors?country={country} from /directors/{country}:
add_action('init',  function () {
    add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)', 'country=');
    add_rewrite_rule('.*directors/([^/]+)[/]?$', '?pagename=directors&country=$matches[1]');    
});

Then WP adds this rule on the .htaccess when permalinks are flushed.
RewriteRule ^.*directors/([^/]+)[/]?$ /?pagename=directors&country=$matches[1] [QSA,L]

But when I try to pass, for example /directors/usa, WP automatically redirects me to /directors/ and therefore no country arg is passed.
How can I fix that? Thanks!

you can follow these steps..

For add rewrite rules:
add_action('init', function () {
add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)', 'country=');
add_rewrite_rule('^directors/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=directors&country=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

To prevent redirects:
add_filter('redirect_canonical', function ($redirect_url, $requested_url) {
return (strpos($requested_url, '/directors/') !== false) ? false : $redirect_url;
}, 10, 2);

for whitelist query variable:
add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
$vars[] = 'country';
return $vars;
});


then just save your permalinks again .. then clear your website caching if you are using the caching plugin.
Let me know after apply them.

Thank! it works!
i think the issue was caused by the lack of "index.php" at the beginning of the rule, if well the rule you propose doesn't create a new rule on htaccess, it's worked like a charm
